# Javascript - can't override a global variable?

Tags: javascript

This line:

```
console.log('crypto: ' + crypto);
```

prints `crypto: [object Crypto]`

If I do this:

```
var crypto = "mystring";
console.log('crypto: ' + crypto);
```

I still get `crypto: [object Crypto]`. I would expect it to print `crypto: mystring`. Why doesn't it?

Comment: Please make a [MCVE]. At the moment, your error cannot be reproduced.

Comment: What does `window.crypto` return?

Comment: @CertainPerformance just inject it in any HTML, load the page and open the console. Are you saying it prints `crypto: mystring` ?

Comment: @Pavitra it returns that Crypto object.

Comment: Why do you want to override the crypto object? And if you want to do so, do you need the crypto object later?

Comment: Just to see if I can. And if I can't, to understand why. I won't need it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to override the crypto object with some string, you can do so like this

```
delete crypto
var crypto = "mystring"
console.log("crypto = " + crypto) // crypto = mystring
```

Answer (score 0):

Crypto is an library in Javascript. Thats why there is a problem i guess.
I tried replacing crypto with other words and it worked fine.

**delete crypto
var crypto = "mystring"
console.log("crypto = " + crypto) // crypto = mystring**

**crypto. This library is an object oriented cryptography toolkit that implements several fundamental cryptographic algorithms including TWOFISH, SERPENT, RIJNDAEL, RSA with key-generation and SHA(SHA-1,224,256,384,512) for JavaScript. ... The unique feature of this library is asynchronous processing.**